# Selenium driver doesn't open window in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, selenium-chromedriver

When I run this code in Jupyter notebook:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Everything seems fine according to the logs:

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 92.0.4515
Get LATEST driver version for 92.0.4515
Driver [C:\Users\username\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\92.0.4515.107\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
```

But the driver doesn't open any Chrome window.

When I execute it from VS Code or Command prompt, it works well.
Could you help me to solve the Jupyter issue please? (I have "not secure connection" when opening Jupyter notebook)

Comment: You could download the driver yourself from this link: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads